# Get path to current directoty with php?

Tags: php

I'd like to get the correct php code to display filepath to a folder on my server. Currently I put the actual filepath in my script which looks like this: /home/username/mydomain.com/dir/upload/

So the script is installed in a subfolder "dir", and I need the path to the "upload" folder

I used this, but it doesn't seem to work, because it seems to put uploaded files into the root:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/upload'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `__DIR__` constant which will contain the script file's directory path.

`echo __DIR__;`

So to get your upload path you could do:

`echo __DIR__ . '/upload/';`

For PHP < 5.3 you can do

`echo dirname(__FILE__);`

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php for other 'Magic Constants'

Comment: ihmo "For PHP < 5.3 " should no longer be a concern today

Comment: Thanks this worked, just needed an extra ' __DIR__ . '/upload/';

Comment: @Federkun - I agree, but a lot of code I come across still uses the `dirname(__FILE__)` approach so I thought I'd mention it.